# TensorFlow random sample feature

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model which consumes data from some TensorFlow records, lets say the data has features `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and label `y` where `y` is either 0 or 1. 
Feature `x3` happens to be a categorical feature. Also, lets assume that all the the labels written to the TFRecords are `1` (all the time `y == 1`).

I want to generate `0` labels on the fly, by randomly changing the value of the feature `x3` so for every example in the TFRecords I will have one example with label `1` (using the original features) and another one that will be generated on the fly labeled `0` with exactly the same features only changing `x3`.

Now I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123879/numpy-random-choice-in-tensorflow) about implementing the random choice mechanism, but my question is how can I pass each example two times through the network, with the changes?