# tf.random.categorical giving strange results

Tags: python, tensorflow, random

I am trying to implement `np.random.choice` in tensorflow. Here is my implementation

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
p=tf.Variable(0,tf.int32)
selection_sample=[i for i in range(10)]#sample to select from
k=tf.convert_to_tensor(selection_sample)
samples = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6]]),1)
sample_selected=tf.cast(samples[0][0],tf.int64)
op=tf.assign(p,k[sample_selected])
    #selection_sample[samples]
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sample_selected.eval())
    print(k.eval())
    print((sess.run(op)))
    print(p.eval())
```

However when sample_selected is for example 1 i expect p.eval to be 1 i.e k[1] but this is not the case. For example running this code a sample output is

```
3
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
1
1
```

yet p.eval should be `k[3]` and `sess.run(op)` should also be `k[3]`
what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123879/numpy-random-choice-in-tensorflow

Comment: My question is on abnormal results and not implementation

Comment: Is this the exact code you run to get your results? Because it has a typo and would not execute anyway.

Comment: I have fixed the issue now it can execute@IcedLance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
print(sample_selected.eval())
```

You get a random value derived from `tf.random.categorical`. That random value is returned by the session and not saved anywhere else.

Then, when you do:

```
print((sess.run(op)))
```

You are assigning the variable `p` a *new* random value produced in this call to `run`. That is the value printed, which is now saved in the variable.

Finally, when you do:

```
print(p.eval())
```

You see the value currently stored in `p`, which is the random value generated in the previous call to `run`.

Comment: how then can I select a number from k based on random probabilities from samples

Comment: @onexpeters I'm not sure what you mean. With `k[sample_selected]` you are getting a random value from `k` selected according to the given probabilities. You can `run` that value, store it in a variable or whatever.

Comment: please notice for example that sample_selected.eval() returns 3 why then is k[3]  outputting 1 and not 3 when k=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

Comment: @onexpeters As I said, every time you call `run` or `eval` the random value will change. You get a different output because the random value in the second call has changed. If you do `print(sess.run((sample_selected, op)))` you will see a matching output.

Comment: Thanks. You are a genius