# Tensorflow: How to chose a random string from a given list of strings using tensorflow operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, random

I have a list of strings like below & I want to do tensorflow operation.
I want to pick a string randomly from `list_2` for a given input string from `list_1`.

My function looks like this;

```
list_1 = ['hello', 'how are you?', 'this is just a test']
list_2 = ['helloooo', 'thanks', 'okay']

def test(string):
    if string in list_1:
        print("list: ", random.choice(list_2)) 
test("hello")
```

How do I achieve this using tensorflow? because I dont find anything `tf.random.choice` in tensorflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy random choice in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123879/numpy-random-choice-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach which is based on Tensorflow Ops:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

list_2 = ['helloooo', 'thanks', 'okay']
len_list = tf.size(list_2)
rand_var = tf.random_uniform([1],0,len_list, dtype=tf.int32)
output = tf.gather(list_2,rand_var[0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
```